# Django turns absolute filepaths into relative, forcing the server to be run from the project folder

Tags: django, webserver

I'm trying to create a website where you can add images to models, which will then be in turn loaded on the homepage. However, I've noticed that when I run my server, it tries to get images from my /home folder.

Here's my models.py:

```
image_directory = join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], "website/images")
class Item(models.Model):
    image = models.FilePathField(path=image_directory, recursive=True)
```

Here's my home.html (I'm just abbreviating it, item is passed in OK:

```
<img src="{{ item.image }}">
```

I run the migrations and run the server, and I'm able to select the image in /admin. The images look like: "sub_img_folder/img.jpg"

Then I go to /home and I get the following errors:

```
Not Found: /home/...absolute-path-to-project.../static/website/images/sub_img_folder/img.jpg
Not Found: /home/static/website/images/sub_img_folder/img.jpg
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's some of my settings.py contents.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
...
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
...
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR + "/static/website/")
MEDIA_URL = "images/"
```

EDIT 2: Just to clarify, the images you add to models are already on the server. You just need to clarify which image in the admin page, hence FilePathField instead of FileField. It somehow doesn't find the image when trying to load it on the home page but it successfully shows and selects in the admin page.

Comment: Please post your STATICFILES_DIRS settings from settings.py and MEDIA settings from urls.py

Comment: What is your BASE_DIR setting? You don't have a MEDIA_URL or MEDIA setting? Are you serving this in production (i.e. DEBUG=False)?

Comment: @MichaelHawkins I just added it but I haven't touched it so that shouldn't be an issue I think. No, this is a development environment. Is not having a MEDIA_URL/MEDIA bad practice?

Comment: The MEDIA directives tell Django where to upload and retrieve user uploaded files, so it may be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Since you are using a FilePathField, it only stores the path on disk, not the URL. The solution would be to use the MEDIA_URL in your template to formulate the URI string, something like this:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ FILE_NAME}}">
```

Where `MEDIA_URL` is your Media URL from settings.py and `FILE_NAME` is the name of the file itself.

It may be better to use an actual `ImageField` or `FileField` which stores all the information you need, or just have a `CharField` with the file name and build the URL like above.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

Try adding the MEDIA elements to your Django settings.py. MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL tell Django how to handle user uploaded files:

In your settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/path/to/media/folder"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
  .......
] += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#media-root

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. The files are already on the server. I added some info in the post, thanks

Comment: If I understand, they display in the admin but not on your homepage? Is your MEDIA_URL set?

Comment: Yeah, it's the weirdest thing. The file exists, it shows in the admin page, and then it throws an error saying it can't find the file with the correct absolute filepath

Comment: So the path you posted (/home/static/website/images/sub_img_folder/img.jpg) is correct? the image resides there?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it was wrong too but I copied and pasted the filepath and used the file command - normal output. I even went to the directory and checked that the file was there too.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the rendered page HTML look like for {{ item.image }}?

Comment: I have some other html and css styling that should go above the image, and that displays fine. It displays the alt image correctly too, so it's definitely not an HTML problem.

Comment: I mean what is the value of SRC in the image tag?

Comment: Sorry about that, when I inspect the image tag it has the absolute filepath /home/...../static/website/images/img.jpg. I think that's the problem because every static image that works has the format src="/static/website/images/img2.jpg"

Comment: Yep, that's what I was getting at. I'll update my answer.